# Creating a Microscopic Black Hole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes

Creating a Bose-Einstein Condensate is real-world means of condensing as much matter into as small a space as possible.  The amount of matter necessary to turn the BEC into a microscopic black hole is calculated based off all of the mass being concentrated inside the:

A) The Helium ATOM, with a radius of 140pm ($1.4\times 10^{-10}$ meters), requiring 94.3 trillion tonnes of Helium ($9.43\times 10^{16}$ kg).

B) The Helium NUCLEUS, with a radius 1.9fm ($1.9\times 10^{-15}$ meters), requiring 1.28 billion tonnes of Helium ($1.28\times 10^{12}$ kg) to create my black hole.

C) Some OTHERvalue determined by the element involved - in this case Helium 4.

Comment: The Schwarzschild radius is dependent on the mass of the object in question. The more helium you have, the greater your Schwarzschild radius.

Answer (score 1):

The Schwarzschild radius has nothing to do with a Bose-Einstein condensate. It describes the radius of a nonrotating uncharged black hole with a specific mass.

"How much helium do I need to create a microscopic black hole?"

Depends on how long you want it to last. Smaller black holes emit more Hawking radiation relative to their size and evaporate more quickly.